# Checkbox inside the "for" (loop), Django

Tags: django, checkbox, django-views, django-templates

my checkbox html :

```
<form method="GET">
    {% for subcategory in subcategories %}
        <div class="filter-items filter-items-count">  
             <div class="filter-item">
                  <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="{{subcategory.id}}" name="subcategory" id="{{subcategory.id}}" {% if subcategory in subcategories1 %} checked {% endif %}>
                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="{{subcategory.id}}">{{subcategory}}</label>
                     </div><!-- End .custom-checkbox -->
                 <span class="item-count">{{subcategory.products.all|length}}</span>
               </div><!-- End .filter-item -->
          </div><!-- End .filter-items -->
{% endfor %}
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary w-100 mt-3">Filter!</button>
</form>
```

it work correctly to make filter.
views :

```
subcatid = request.GET.getlist('subcategory')
```

query string:

```
?subcategory=5&subcategory=6
```

it can be one or more than one, depends on number of subcategories.
but when I go next page i suppose it become like :

```
?page=2&subcategory=5&subcategory=6
```

but it remove earliest subcategory i choose and keep the last one, just one, like :

```
?page=2&subcategory=5
```

acutely when i put Manually `?page=2&subcategory=5&subcategory=6` in url field it works but not from pagination buttons.

so while all checkboxes in filter has same names, `name="subcategory"` i made them unique by changing to `name="{{subcategory}}"`, now each checkbox has unique name, now after tapping next page, Everything is kept, and there is no problem like before,
but in views, I don't know how to get them with deafferents names

```
subcatid = request.GET.getlist('subcategory')
```

Comment: Can you share the logic you wrote for the pagination?

Comment: yesterday I wrote this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68511483/query-url-query-string-problem-about-paginator-and-filter-in-django

Comment: whole of my pagination view and html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `QueryDict` to the object that does not contain any `page` parameter with:

```
def subcategory(request, category_url):
    # …
    reqget = request.GET.copy()
    reqget.pop('page', None)
    ctx = {
        # …
        'reqget': reqget
    }
    return render(request, 'products/subcategory.html', ctx)
```

Then in the template, the links to go to the previous/next page will `urlencode` the `reqget`:

```
<a href="?page={{ products.previous_page_number }}&{{ reqget.urlencode }}" aria-label="Previous" tabindex="-1" class="page-link page-link-prev" aria-disabled="true">
```

Comment: Thank you. it works now, but it get queries in url twice, like : `/?page=3&subcategory=6&subcategory=6&subcategory=5&subcategory=6`

Comment: @MehranBahrami: are you submitting the form a second time? I had the idea that you were stuck with the pagination, not with submitting the form.

Comment: @MehranBahrami: as for the form, I would advise to use a Django form, and perhaps manually render that. This will ensure that the form is filled in with the checkboxes: see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually

Comment: actually, each time i tap next page or previous page, url not get clear, just add same things next of the before strings. it works correctly is display but the list sent to views is like :  `['6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '5', '6']` i think its because used checked for selects . but i don't submit them, just taping next or previou page.

Comment: its just small filter, unfortunately i didn't use Django form from beginning

Comment: @MehranBahrami: It looks like your prev/next are part of the form, perhaps even submit the form, but these pagination links should simply visit a new page with `<a href="...">`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68511483/query-url-query-string-problem-about-paginator-and-filter-in-django i changed how you said by adding `{{ reqget.urlencode }}` its correct ?

Comment: @MehranBahrami: I think for the `<form>`, you need to specify the action as `action="?"` to prevent "reusing" the old options.

Comment: and i that html file i just have one form and just for that selects

Comment: i changed to  `action="?"` but also like before

Comment: its not about : `reqget = request.GET.copy()` ?

Comment: when i `print(reqget)` it give me back `<QueryDict: {'page': ['1'], 'category': ['3', '3', '3','2','1','1']}>` if we use set() for category list and remove same numbers. it going work ?

Comment: @MehranBahrami: is it possible to ask a *new* question where you share the full view together all items in the template that are relevant, and explain *what* you are doing?

Comment: sure, I can edit here and show whole of my template

Comment: I posted new answer, please check it

Comment: @MehranBahrami: please ask a new *question*. Include the template together with the (full) view, and the *steps* to reproduce the problem...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68519774/reusing-old-options-from-pagination-and-filter-django