# Reusing old options from pagination and filter Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

view :

```
def subcategory(request, category_url):
    category = get_object_or_404(Category, category_url=category_url)
    subcategories = Subcategory.objects.filter(category=category)
    products_list = Product.objects.filter(product_category=category)
    subcatid = request.GET.getlist('subcategory')
    print(subcatid)
    if subcatid:
        ids = [int(id) for id in subcatid]
        subcategories1 = Subcategory.objects.filter(category=category, id__in=ids)
        products_list = Product.objects.filter(product_category=category, product_subcategory__in=subcategories1)
    else:
        subcategories1 = None
        products_list = Product.objects.filter(product_category=category)
    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    paginator = Paginator(products_list, 12)
    try:
        products = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        products = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        products = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        wishlist = get_object_or_404(Wishlist, user=request.user.profile)
    else:    
        wishlist = None   
    reqget = request.GET.copy()
    reqget.pop('page', None)      
    ctx = {'products':products,
    'products_list':products_list,
    'wishlist':wishlist,
    'subcategories':subcategories,
    'category':category,
    'subcategories1':subcategories1,
    'reqget': reqget,
    }
    return render(request, 'products/subcategory.html', ctx)
```

template :

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% load ratings %}
{% load humanize %}


{% block title %}ماهوت کالکشن | دسته بندی محصولات {% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
<main class="main">
    <div class="page-header text-center">
        <div class="container">
            <h1 class="page-title">{{category.category_name}}<span>دسته بندی</span></h1>
        </div><!-- End .container -->
    </div><!-- End .page-header -->
    <nav aria-label="breadcrumb" class="breadcrumb-nav mb-2">
        <div class="container">
            <ol class="breadcrumb">
                <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="">{{q}} فروشگاه</a></li>
                <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="/products/">دسته بندی</a></li>
                <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">{{category.category_name}}</li>
            </ol>
        </div><!-- End .container -->
    </nav><!-- End .breadcrumb-nav -->

    <div class="page-content">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-9">
                    <div class="toolbox">
                        <div class="toolbox-left">
                            <div class="toolbox-info">
                                محصولات این دسته : <span>{{products_list.all|length}}</span> محصول
                            </div><!-- End .toolbox-info -->
                        </div><!-- End .toolbox-left -->

                        <div class="toolbox-right">
                            <div class="toolbox-sort">
                                <label for="sortby">مرتب سازی براساس :</label>
                                <div class="select-custom">
                                    <select name="sortby" id="sortby" class="form-control">
                                        <option value="popularity" selected="selected">بیشترین خرید</option>
                                        <option value="rating">محبوب ترین</option>
                                        <option value="date">بر ارساس تاریخ</option>
                                        <option value="">ارزان ترین</option>
                                        <option value="">گران ترین</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div><!-- End .toolbox-sort -->
                        </div><!-- End .toolbox-right -->
                    </div><!-- End .toolbox -->

                    <div class="products mb-3">
                        <div class="row justify-content-start">
                            {% for cat in products %}
                            <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
                                <div class="product product-7 text-center">
                                    <figure class="product-media">
                                        {% if cat.product_all_price == "0" %}
                                        <span class="product-label label-out">ناموجود</span>
                                        {% elif cat.discount_price %}
                                        <span class="product-label label-new">فروش ویژه</span>
                                        {% endif %} 
                                        <a href="{{cat.product_url}}/">
                                            <img src="{{cat.product_img1.url}}" alt="Product image" class="product-image">
                                        </a>

                                        <div class="product-action-vertical">
                                        {% if cat in wishlist.items.all %}
                                            <a href="/products/delete-from-wishlist/{{cat.id}}/" class="btn-product-icon btn-wishlist btn-expandable"><span>حذف</span></a>
                                        {% else %}
                                            <a href="/products/add-to-wishlist/{{cat.id}}/" class="btn-product-icon btn-wishlist btn-expandable"><span>افزودن به علاقه مندی ها</span></a>
                                        {% endif %} 
                                        </div><!-- End .product-action-vertical -->

                                        <div class="product-action">
                                            <a href="/products/category/{{cat.product_category.category_url}}/{{cat.product_subcategory.subcategory_url}}/{{cat.product_url}}" class="btn-product btn-cart"><span>مشاهده محصول</span></a>
                                        </div><!-- End .product-action -->
                                    </figure><!-- End .product-media -->

                                    <div class="product-body">
                                        <div class="product-cat">
                                            <a href="/products/category/{{cat.product_category.category_url}}">
                                            {% if not cat.product_subcategory.subcategory_name %}
                                                {{cat.product_category.category_name}}
                                            {% else %}
                                                {{cat.product_subcategory.subcategory_name}}
                                            {% endif %}    
                                            </a>
                                        </div><!-- End .product-cat -->
                                        <h3 class="product-title"><a href="/products/category/{{cat.product_category.category_url}}/{{cat.product_subcategory.subcategory_url}}/{{cat.product_url}}">{{cat.product_model}}</a></h3><!-- End .product-title -->
                                        <div class="product-price">
                                            
                                                {% if cat.discount_price %}
                                                <span class="new-price">{{cat.discount_price|intcomma}} تومان</span>
                                                {% else %} 
                                                <span class="price">{{cat.price|intcomma}} تومان</span>
                                                {% endif %} 
                                            
                                        </div><!-- End .product-price -->
                                        <div class="ratings-container">
                                                {% ratings cat %}
                                        </div><!-- End .rating-container -->
                                    </div><!-- End .product-body -->
                                </div><!-- End .product -->
                            </div><!-- End .col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 -->
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div><!-- End .row -->
                    </div><!-- End .products -->
                    <nav aria-label="Page navigation">
                        <ul class="pagination justify-content-center">
                            {% if products.number|add:'-4' > 1 %}
                            <li class="page-item">
                                <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ products.number|add:'-5' }}" aria-label="Previous" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">
                                    <span aria-hidden="true"></span><<
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            {% endif %}
                            
                            {% if products.has_previous %}
                            <li class="page-item ">
                                <a class="page-link page-link-prev" href="?page={{ products.previous_page_number }}{% for key, value in request.GET.items %}{% if key != 'page' %}&{{ key }}={{ value }}{% endif %}{% endfor %}&{{ reqget.urlencode }}" aria-label="Previous" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">
                                    <span aria-hidden="true"><i class="icon-long-arrow-right"></i></span>قبلی
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            {% else %}
                            <li class="page-item disabled">
                                <a class="page-link page-link-prev" href="" aria-label="Previous" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">
                                    <span aria-hidden="true"><i class="icon-long-arrow-right"></i></span>قبلی
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            {% endif %}

                            {% for i in products.paginator.page_range %}
                            {% if products.number == i %}
                            <li class="page-item active" aria-current="page"><a class="page-link" href="">{{ i }}</a></li>
                            {% elif i > products.number|add:'-5' and i < products.number|add:'4' %}
                            <li class="page-item" aria-current="page"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ i }}{% for key, value in request.GET.items %}{% if key != 'page' %}&{{ key }}={{ value }}{% endif %}{% endfor %}&{{ reqget.urlencode }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
                            {% endif %}
                            {% endfor %}

                            {% if products.has_next %}
                            <li class="page-item">
                                <a class="page-link page-link-next" href="?page={{ products.next_page_number }}{% for key, value in request.GET.items %}{% if key != 'page' %}&{{ key }}={{ value }}{% endif %}{% endfor %}&{{ reqget.urlencode }}" aria-label="Next">
                                    بعدی <span aria-hidden="true"><i class="icon-long-arrow-left"></i></span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            {% else %}
                            <li class="page-item disabled">
                                <a class="page-link page-link-next" href="" aria-label="Next">
                                    بعدی <span aria-hidden="true"><i class="icon-long-arrow-left"></i></span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            {% endif %}

                            {% if products.paginator.num_pages > products.number|add:'4' %}
                            <li class="page-item">
                                <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ products.number|add:'5' }}" aria-label="Previous" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">
                                    <span aria-hidden="true"></span>>>
                                </a>
                            {% endif %}
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div><!-- End .col-lg-9 -->
                <aside class="col-lg-3 order-lg-first">
                    <div class="sidebar sidebar-shop">
                        <div class="widget widget-clean">
                            <label>فیلترها : </label>
                            <a href="#" class="sidebar-filter-clear">پاک کردن همه</a>
                        </div><!-- End .widget widget-clean -->

                        <div class="widget widget-collapsible">
                            <h3 class="widget-title">
                                <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#widget-1" role="button" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="widget-1">
                                    دسته بندی
                                </a>
                            </h3><!-- End .widget-title -->

                            <div class="collapse show" id="widget-1">
                                <div class="widget-body">
                                    <div class="filter-items filter-items-count">
                                        <form method="GET" action="?">
                                        {% for subcategory in subcategories %}
                                        <div class="filter-items filter-items-count">  
                                            <div class="filter-item">
                                                    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                                        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="{{subcategory.id}}" name="subcategory" id="{{subcategory.id}}" {% if subcategory in subcategories1 %} checked {% endif %}>
                                                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="{{subcategory.id}}">{{subcategory}}</label>
                                                    </div><!-- End .custom-checkbox -->
                                                    <span class="item-count">{{subcategory.products.all|length}}</span>
                                            </div><!-- End .filter-item -->
                                        </div><!-- End .filter-items -->
                                        {% endfor %}
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary w-100 mt-3">فیلتر کن</button>
                                        </form>
                                    </div><!-- End .filter-items -->
                                </div><!-- End .widget-body -->
                            </div><!-- End .collapse -->
                        </div><!-- End .widget -->
                    </div><!-- End .sidebar sidebar-shop -->
                </aside><!-- End .col-lg-3 -->
            </div><!-- End .row -->
        </div><!-- End .container -->
    </div><!-- End .page-content -->
</main><!-- End .main -->
{% endblock content %}

{% block scripts %}
<script>
    const filterBtn = document.getElementById('filterBtn');
    const filter = document.getElementById('filter');
    filterBtn.addEventListener('click', () =>{
        filter.submit()
    })
</script>
{% endblock scripts %}
```

my whole html file and view, I get same category queries in queries string like `?page=2&category=3&category=1&category=2&category=3` and when i print `reqget` show me `<QueryDict: {'page': ['1'], 'category': ['3', '1', '2','3']}>`
problems about filter  each time i tap next page or previous page, url not get clear, just add same things next of the before strings. it works correctly is display but the list sent to views is like : ['6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '5', '6'] i think its because used checked for selects . but i don't submit them, just taping next or previou page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove the <s>`{% for key, value in request.GET.items %}{% if key != 'page' %}&{{ key }}={{ value }}{% endif %}{% endfor %}`</s> parts from the links that link to the previous, next, or another page. The link is thus:

```
<a href="?page={{ i }}&{{ reqget.urlencode }}">…</a>
```

You thus should remove the logic that you implemented yourself to render the key-value pairs, since that is what the `reqget.urlencode()` does.